# Configure Java heap space with Spark

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a file with few hundred mega bytes by oversampling a small array in spark and save as object file to hdfs system created by spark-ec2 script:

```
//Accepted arguments
val URI = args(0)
val repNum = args(1).toInt

//Create a LabeledPoint array of size 2
val labelPts = sc.parallelize(Array(LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0)),
  LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 8.0, 6.0, 9.0, 9.0))))

//Oversampling repNum LabeledPoints from the array above
val overSample = labelPts.takeSample(true, repNum, 1)

//output oversampling result as object
sc.parallelize(overSample).saveAsObjectFile(URI)
```

the cluster is created by script:

```
spark-ec2 -k spark -i ~/.ssh/spark.pem -s 1 launch my-spark-cluster
```

and my bundled spark application is submitted by script:

```
./spark-submit \
--class SimpleApp \
--master spark://ec2-52-1-94-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 \
--executor-memory=4g \
--driver-memory=4g \
--conf spark.akka.frameSize=10000 \
--conf spark.core.connection.auth.wait.timeout=1000 \
~/oversample-assembly-1.0.jar \
hdfs://ec2-52-1-94-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/user/root/oversampleOut \
70000000
```

Then it throws a `EXCEPTION: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I don't know what's wrong with it because if my `repNum` is set to 6000000, there will be no error and the output file is around 490m, so I suspect that the java heap space is still capped by 512m, however the I've set `--executor-memory=4g` and the worknode in this cluster has 7.5GB memory. What's the problem here?

Comment: Does it run as a 64bit process?

Comment: @sturcotte06 I don't know how to check if it's run as a 64bit process, but it's a Ubuntu 14.04 64bit EC2 instance and the jvm is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: did you solve this? I am facing the same issue.. my code is working well in spark shell and on the same data set, but failing when i try to package it and run it through spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

You can provide extra java options using sparks run time option `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` also decrease the memory used for caching using `spark.storage.memoryFraction`  for more information follow this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html)